# JIRA TOMCAT6 FIND MY .JAR :(

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

We are working with a *Tomcat6* server. We have deployed our *.war* file inside the *webapp* folder.

Tomcat cannot find our *.jar* file inside

```
C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\webapps\MYSITE\WEB-INF\lib\mycooljarfile.jar
```

, but if we put inside of the `C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\lib it can find mycooljarfile.jar` it finds it and our application works as intended.

The error message that we receive when it is deployed in the `war-root` is

```
"noclassdeffounderror could not initialize class"
```

Do we need to modify the classpaths? And if so, where are the located? We used the JIRA.exe for jira 4.4 on windows.

Comment: Please do not type the entire title in caps, it appears as if you are shouting.

Comment: How your jar file correlated with `jira`? Does it have dependency from jira libs?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have /WEB-INF and /lib on the same level.  If that's true, it should be /WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: IM sorry its actually set up like this C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\webapps\MYSITE\WEB-INF\lib\mycooljarfile.jar